# acer_wmi: unable to find wmid devices - ubuntu 14.04

Tags: error-handling

On Acer aspire 5532 after installation getting on boot message:
          acer_wmi: unable to find wmid devices
Laptop is working well, but why not to fix this. Any help to fix it (not to cover) would be very welcome.

Comment: I am using Acer Aspire 5737Z and got the same message. If it helps, the error message appeared on Ubuntu 12.10, 13.04, 13.10 and now 14.04. I didn't use any other version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Try blacklisting the acer-wmi kernel module:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

add `blacklist acer_wmi` as a new line at the bottom of this file.

then reboot.

Or if you like one-line tricks:

```
echo blacklist acer-wmi | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-acer-wmi.conf
```

[source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1233149&page=3)

The acer-wmi kernel module enables you to control the following:

- the wireless LAN card radio
- inbuilt Bluetooth adapter
- inbuilt 3G card
- mail LED of your laptop
- brightness of the LCD panel

For some acer laptop models - there is a conflict between the Acer firmware and the kernel implementation.  This is why you need to blacklist.

If you need any of the capabilities above and they are not enabled by other kernel modules then you have a choice - live without the capability ... or live with the brief VT switch during boot.

Comment: This hides error notification but does not solve it. The problem is still present, and on an accurate usage users of Acer Aspire 5532 will notice laptop lid doesn't suspend pc, etc. My question is pretty concrete- How to solve this and not to bypass it. This model worked fine with ubuntu until 2 years ago. Something changed on new kernels. Does anyone know what did change?

Comment: If you do not believe this resolves your issue, then the only real solution you have is to raise a bug report `ubuntu-bug kernel` and work with the kernel guys to find a fix.  You'll need to identify which kernel in the past it did work.  You'll need to test the latest kernels and advise the kernel developers of this information.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem on my Acer Aspire 5534 laptop with bios version 1.10 with Xubuntu 16.04 LTS as well as Ubuntu Mate 16.04 LTS. The problem is resolved by updating the bios to version 1.18. The bios update was downloaded from Acer's website.
Enjoy.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)