# Can't connect wifi with Intel AC 7265 on Ubuntu 15.10, Asus k501UX

Tags: wireless, drivers, 15.10, asus

I just got a new Asus k501UX ([specs](https://www.asus.com/Notebooks/K501UX/specifications/)) and after installing Ubuntu 15.10 in dual boot with the windows 10 I find that wifi doesn't work. It did work in the live USB that I installed it from.

I have installed the updated driver using the below method.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/OpenELEC/iwlwifi-firmware.git
cd iwlwifi-firmware/firmware
sudo cp iwlwifi-7265*  /lib/firmware
```

It worked for others but not me. I suspect that it is because the wifi is hardblocked. It the Network manager it states "Wi-Fi is disabled by hardware switch". However there isn't a hardware switch on this laptop. There is Fn+f2 but that doesn't work.

Both commands dont unblock all.

```
sudo rfkill unblock all AND sudo rfkill unblock wifi
```

Here are some details that may assist.

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 03 Feb 2016 14:22 AEDT +1100

Booted last: 03 Feb 2016 00:00 AEDT +1100

Script from: 27 Sep 2015 00:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
Release:    15.10
Codename:   wily

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.4.0-040400-lowlatency #201601101930 SMP PREEMPT Mon Jan 11 00:38:46 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, nouveau.nomodeset=0, acpi_osi=Linux

##### desktop ###########################

sed: can't read /root/.dmrc: No such file or directory

Could not be determined.

##### lspci #############################

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:200f]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095a] (rev 59)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 [8086:5110]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:57ed Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

1: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes

##### lsmod #############################

iwlmvm                294912  0
mac80211              643072  1 iwlmvm
iwlwifi               208896  1 iwlmvm
asus_nb_wmi            24576  0
asus_wmi               28672  1 asus_nb_wmi
cfg80211              557056  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwlmvm
sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi
mxm_wmi                16384  0
compat                 16384  4 cfg80211,iwlwifi,mac80211,iwlmvm
wmi                    20480  2 mxm_wmi,asus_wmi
video                  40960  2 i915,asus_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'enp2s0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:192.168.0.105  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::<IP6 'enp2s0' [IF]>/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:20742 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:15728 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:18581752 (18.5 MB)  TX bytes:1888008 (1.8 MB)

wlp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlp3s0' [IF]>  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

##### iwconfig ##########################

enp2s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off


##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp2s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp2s0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp2s0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 192.168.0.1

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager
    Wicd

Running:

root       652     1  0 13:34 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp2s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp2s0' [IF]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:02:00.0/net/enp2s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enp2s0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Auto Ethernet
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       ab33df8c-f9c6-4bab-bf1c-219fe6e902de
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     100 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{0}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   ab33df8c-f9c6-4bab-bf1c-219fe6e902de | Auto Ethernet
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.0.105/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.0.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        expiry = 1454470317
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        next_server = 192.168.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       broadcast_address = 192.168.0.255
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       routers = 192.168.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 600
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       ip_address = 192.168.0.105
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       domain_name_servers = 192.168.0.1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       network_number = 192.168.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.0.1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::<IP6 'enp2s0' [IF]>/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp3s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Intel Corporation
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        Wireless 7265 (Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265)
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         iwlwifi
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 4.4.0-040400-lowlatency
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               15.195093.0
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlp3s0' [IF]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:03:00.0/net/wlp3s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   yes
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 

SSID  BSSID  MODE  CHAN  FREQ  RATE  SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  ACTIVE  * 

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Wi-Fi connection 1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Wi-Fi connection 1 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=trafficlogger
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Australia/Melbourne (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

enp2s0    no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

wlp3s0    32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 14 : 2.484 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
          Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
          Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz

##### iwlist scan #######################

enp2s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlp3s0    Interface doesn't support scanning : Network is down

##### module infos ######################

[iwlmvm]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-040400-lowlatency/updates/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/iwlmvm.ko
version:        backported from Linux (next-20150731-0-g37bd1ea) using backports backports-20150731-0-g2af997b
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
description:    The new Intel(R) wireless AGN driver for Linux
srcversion:     361F6B10C0D6F3E53F6658C
depends:        iwlwifi,mac80211,compat,cfg80211
vermagic:       4.4.0-040400-lowlatency SMP preempt mod_unload modversions 
parm:           init_dbg:set to true to debug an ASSERT in INIT fw (default: false (bool)
parm:           power_scheme:power management scheme: 1-active, 2-balanced, 3-low power, default: 2 (int)
parm:           tfd_q_hang_detect:TFD queues hang detection (default: true (bool)

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-040400-lowlatency/updates/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
version:        backported from Linux (next-20150731-0-g37bd1ea) using backports backports-20150731-0-g2af997b
srcversion:     0D75D5CB20D73FC00FCD060
depends:        cfg80211,compat
vermagic:       4.4.0-040400-lowlatency SMP preempt mod_unload modversions 
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[iwlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-040400-lowlatency/updates/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
version:        backported from Linux (next-20150731-0-g37bd1ea) using backports backports-20150731-0-g2af997b
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2015 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-12.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-12.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-IWL3160_UCODE_API_OK.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-12.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000-12.ucode
srcversion:     D5746F80A440F6012DA5DF8
depends:        compat,cfg80211
vermagic:       4.4.0-040400-lowlatency SMP preempt mod_unload modversions 
parm:           debug:debug output mask (uint)
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size_8K:enable 8K amsdu size (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (default: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           d0i3_disable:disable d0i3 functionality (default: Y) (bool)
parm:           lar_disable:disable LAR functionality (default: N) (bool)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality (default: Y) (bool)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           fw_monitor:firmware monitor - to debug FW (default: false - needs lots of memory) (bool)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-040400-lowlatency/updates/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
version:        backported from Linux (next-20150731-0-g37bd1ea) using backports backports-20150731-0-g2af997b
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     75463EDBD0CFDDF127DF5B4
depends:        compat
vermagic:       4.4.0-040400-lowlatency SMP preempt mod_unload modversions 
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[iwlmvm]
init_dbg: N
power_scheme: 2
tfd_q_hang_detect: Y

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
probe_wait_ms: 500

[iwlwifi]
11n_disable: 8
amsdu_size_8K: 0
antenna_coupling: 0
bt_coex_active: Y
d0i3_disable: Y
debug: 0
fw_monitor: N
fw_restart: Y
lar_disable: N
led_mode: 0
nvm_file: (null)
power_level: 0
power_save: N
swcrypto: 0
uapsd_disable: Y

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

grep: /etc/udev/rules.d/*net*.rules: No such file or directory

##### dmesg #############################

[    4.097039] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[    4.097917] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp2s0: link is not ready
[    4.107669] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link down
[    4.107754] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp2s0: link is not ready
[   78.085526] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: link up
[   78.085533] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp2s0: link becomes ready
[ 2010.668221] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq
[ 2010.877686] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware patch completed and activated

########## wireless info END ############
```

Here are some more

```
luddite@luddite-laptop:~$ ifconfig -a
enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 30:5a:3a:8b:47:9f  
          inet addr:192.168.0.105  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::325a:3aff:fe8b:479f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8215 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7093 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:5267943 (5.2 MB)  TX bytes:926069 (926.0 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:47 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:47 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:7287 (7.2 KB)  TX bytes:7287 (7.2 KB)

wlp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr dc:53:60:ea:50:24  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

luddite@luddite-laptop:~$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095a] (rev 59)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 [8086:5110]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
luddite@luddite-laptop:~$ rfkill list
1: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes

luddite@luddite-laptop:~$ sudo rfkill unblock all
[sudo] password for luddite: 
luddite@luddite-laptop:~$ sudo -i
root@luddite-laptop:~# rfkill list
1: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
4: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
root@luddite-laptop:~# rfkill unblock wifi
root@luddite-laptop:~# rfkill list
1: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
4: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

luddite@luddite-laptop:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 192.168.0.1
luddite@luddite-laptop:~$ dmesg | grep iwl
[    2.865393] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Unsupported splx structure
[    2.927125] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 15.195093.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    3.009263] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7265, REV=0x210
[    3.009336] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    3.009614] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    3.030289] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    3.037287] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
luddite@luddite-laptop:~$ ls -al /lib/firmware | grep 7265
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  736844 Feb  2 14:15 iwlwifi-7265-10.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  880604 Feb  2 14:15 iwlwifi-7265-12.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  885224 Feb  2 14:15 iwlwifi-7265-13.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1180224 Feb  2 14:15 iwlwifi-7265-14.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1180356 Feb  2 14:15 iwlwifi-7265-15.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1180356 Feb  2 14:15 iwlwifi-7265-16.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1180412 Feb  2 14:15 iwlwifi-7265-17.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  690452 Feb  2 14:15 iwlwifi-7265-8.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  697828 Feb  2 14:15 iwlwifi-7265-9.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  740436 Feb  2 14:15 iwlwifi-7265D-10.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1002800 Feb  2 14:15 iwlwifi-7265D-12.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1008692 Feb  2 14:15 iwlwifi-7265D-13.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1384256 Feb  2 14:15 iwlwifi-7265D-14.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1384060 Feb  2 14:15 iwlwifi-7265D-15.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1384500 Feb  2 14:15 iwlwifi-7265D-16.ucode
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1383020 Feb  2 14:15 iwlwifi-7265D-17.ucode
```

I can quickly provide more details or try anything as requested to solve this. Currently no wifi means not useful...

Comment: sudo service network-manager restart fails to assist due to the phy0 wlan card being hardblocked.

Answer (score 1):

First thing to do it to uninstall the backports

```
cd backports-20150731
sudo make uninstall
```

Then we try a module parameter

```
echo "options asus-nb-wmi wapf=4" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/asus-nb-wmi.conf
```

Reboot and see if wireless is still blocked, if it is still blocked the FN combo should clear the block

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, try this:`sudo service network-manager restart`.
I had a similar problem with an Asus and this did the trick.

Comment: I've tried that with rebooting also. Did you install the latest driver as I did? 

I'm confused as to why the live USB wifi would work but not the installed?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the exact same Asus notebook model in Kubuntu 14.04. I fixed it with the terminal command:

> echo blacklist asus-nb-wmi | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-asus-nb-wmi.conf

I am not an expert, apparently this sort of error has happened to similar devices. In this answer to an Acer computer [acer_wmi: unable to find wmid devices - ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450399/acer-wmi-unable-to-find-wmid-devices-ubuntu-14-04) it had something to do with a conflict between Acer firmware and the kernel implementation. I assume the same problem exsits with the Asus K501UX.

If putting .conf doesn't do anything at the end of the line, try the same command with .ko